# Is this a new sorting algorithm? [with Java and Pseudo-code implementation]

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I know this may be a stupid question, maybe the most stupid question today, but I have to ask it: *Have I invented this sorting algorithm?*

Yesterday, I had a little inspiration about an exchange-based sorting algorithm. Today, I implemented it, and it worked.

It probably already exists, since there are many not-so-popular sorting algorithms out there that has little or none information about, and almost no implementation of them exist.

Description: *Basically, this algorithm takes an item, them a pair, then an item again... until the end of the list. For each item/pair, compare EVERY two items at the same radius distance from pair space or item, until a border of the array is reached, and then exchange those items if needed. Repeat this for each pair/item of the list.*

An English-based pseudo-code:

```
FOR i index to last index of Array (starting from 0)
  L index is i - 1
  R index is i + 1

  //Odd case, where i is the center
  WHILE (L is in array range and R is in array range)
    IF item Array[L] is greater than Array[R]
       EXCHANGE item Array[L] with Array[R]
    END-IF

    ADD 1 to R
    REST 1 to L
  END-WHILE

  //Even case, where i is not the center
  L index is now i
  R index in now i + 1
  WHILE (L is in array range and R is in array range)
    IF item Array[L] is greater than Array[R]
       EXCHANGE Array[L] with Array[R]
    END-IF

    ADD 1 to R
    REST 1 to L
  END-WHILE

END FOR
```

This is the implementation in Java:

```java
//package sorting;

public class OrbitSort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numbers ={ 15, 8, 6, 3, 11, 1, 2, 0, 14, 13, 7, 9, 4, 10, 5, 12 };

        System.out.println("Original list:");
        display(numbers);

        sort(numbers);

        System.out.println("\nSorted list:");
        display(numbers);
    }

    //Sorting algorithm
    public static void sort(int[] array) {
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            int L = i - 1;
            int R = i + 1;

            //Odd case (with a central item)
            while(L >= 0 && R < array.length){
                if(array[L] > array[R])
                    swap(array, L, R);

                L--;
                R++;
            }

            //Even case (with no central item)
            L = i;
            R = i + 1;
            while(L >= 0 && R < array.length) {
                if(array[L] > array[R])
                    swap(array, L, R);

                L--;
                R++;
            }
        }
    }

    //Swap two items in array.
    public static void swap(int[] array, int x, int y) {
        int temp = array[x];
        array[x] = array[y];
        array[y] = temp;
    }

    //Display items
    public static void display(int[] numbers){
        for(int i: numbers)
            System.out.print(" " + i);

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

I know can be shorter, but it's just an early implementation.

It probably runs in O(n^2), but I'm not sure.

So, what do you think? Does it already exists?

Comment: Thank you for syntax highlight, Ibonn!

Comment: The problem with these questions is: If there is a "yes" answer, it is quite straight forward. If there isn't, you cannot really give reference and explain why it is the case. For this reason, I think it is not a good question for SO, but the community might disagree with me.

Comment: Man, I remember when I thought I invented a new sorting algorithm.  It was still a cool trick -- Quicksort partitioning around the _mean_ instead of the median, and some nifty hacks to accumulate sums efficiently during the partition step.

Comment: Yeah, I'm a bit excited with this algorithm. However, I believe it can be useful anyway.

Comment: in order to test your new algorithm , run it on all of the possible combinations of the array , or use shuffling of arrays on a large number of times.

Comment: Can you describe the operation of your algorithm in plain English as well as providing code?  It's usually a lot easier to understand the algorithm when the key ideas are presented in natural language.  Thanks... I'm looking forward to learning more about this!

Comment: @templatetypedef Cobolic pseudo-code added!

Comment: Sorry to bother, but the pseudocode doesn't really help here (it just restates the code).  Could you describe intuitively what the sorting algorithm is doing?  For example, selection sort would be "repeatedly find the smallest element not yet placed, then move it to its proper position."  The COBOL-esque code doesn't say anything that the Java didn't.

Comment: You can rest assured that it is O(n^2) in the number of comparisons. Take an array A of odd-size n with indices [0, n) . When i = floor(n/2), the first inner loop performs floor(n/2) operations, and the second inner loop too. When i = floor(n/2) +/- 1, the first inner loop performs floor(n/2) - 1, and the same for the second inner loop. Etc. Now, I don't remember seeing this exact sorting algorithm so your main question stands.

Comment: Just to complement, the worst case for the number of swaps is also O(n^2) which happens for the case of a decreasing array, i.e. `a[i] > a[j], i < j`.

Comment: @templatetypedef Basically, this algorithm takes an item, then a pair, then an item again... until the end of the list. For each item/pair, compare the two items at the same radius distance from pair space  or item, and then exchange them if needed. Repeat this for each pair/item of the list.

Comment: @mmgp Thank you for that interesting observation! I know this is not a great algorithm for sorting nothing, but I think it's important to share it, since some people can modify it to make it useful for something I cannot imagine yet.

Comment: @Josell of course, I support that. Now, what templatetypedef is after is actually some formal documentation of your implementation. For a good starter, if you can provide loop invariants everyone will be happier :)

Comment: Want to add, that you could try to impement an abort if the array is already sorted (like bubble sort does), within those inner loops. As far as I understand your algo, it will loop through, no matter what.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To me, it looks like a modified bubble sort algo, which may perform better for certain arrangements of input elements.
Altough not necessarily fair, I did a benchmark with warmup cycles using your input array, for comparison of:

- [java.util.Arrays.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28int%5B%5D%29), which is a <strike>merge</strike> quick sort implementation
- BubbleSort.sort(), a java implementation of the bubble sort algo
- OrbitSort.sort(), your algo

Results:

```
input size: 8192
warmup iterations: 32

Arrays.sort()
    iterations : 10000
    total time : 4940.0ms
    avg time   : 0.494ms

BubbleSort.sort()
    iterations : 100
    total time : 8360.0ms
    avg time   : 83.6ms

OrbitSort.sort()
    iterations : 100
    total time : 8820.0ms
    avg time   : 88.2ms
```

Of course, the performance depends on input size and arrangement

Straightforward code:

```java
package com.sam.tests;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

public class SortBenchmark {

    public static class OrbitSort {
        // Sorting algorithm
        public static void sort(int[] array) {
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                int L = i - 1;
                int R = i + 1;

                // Odd case (with a central item)
                while (L >= 0 && R < array.length) {
                    if (array[L] > array[R])
                        swap(array, L, R);

                    L--;
                    R++;
                }

                // Even case (with no central item)
                L = i;
                R = i + 1;
                while (L >= 0 && R < array.length) {
                    if (array[L] > array[R])
                        swap(array, L, R);

                    L--;
                    R++;
                }
            }
        }

        // Swap two items in array.
        public static void swap(int[] array, int x, int y) {
            int temp = array[x];
            array[x] = array[y];
            array[y] = temp;
        }
    }

    public static class BubbleSort {

        public static void sort(int[] numbers) {
            boolean swapped = true;
            for (int i = numbers.length - 1; i > 0 && swapped; i--) {
                swapped = false;
                for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                    if (numbers[j] > numbers[j + 1]) {
                        int temp = numbers[j];
                        numbers[j] = numbers[j + 1];
                        numbers[j + 1] = temp;
                        swapped = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static class TestDataFactory {

        public static enum ElementOrder {
            Ascending, Descending, Random
        }

        public static int[] createIntArray(final int size, final ElementOrder elementOrder) {
            int[] array = new int[size];

            switch (elementOrder) {
            case Ascending:
                for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
                    array[i] = i;
                break;
            case Descending:
                for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
                    array[i] = size - i - 1;
                break;
            case Random:
            default:
                Random rg = new Random(System.nanoTime());
                for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
                    array[i] = rg.nextInt(size);
                break;
            }

            return array;
        }
    }

    public static class Benchmark {
        // misc constants
        public static final int  NANOS_PER_MSEC                    = 1000000;

        // config constants
        public static final int  BIGDECIMAL_PRECISION              = 6;

        // constant defaults
        public static final long AUTOTUNING_MIN_ITERATIONS_DEFAULT = 1;
        public static final long AUTOTUNING_MIN_DURATION_DEFAULT   = 125;

        public static final long BENCHMARK_MIN_ITERATIONS_DEFAULT  = 1;
        public static final long BENCHMARK_MAX_ITERATIONS_DEFAULT  = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        public static final long BENCHMARK_TARGET_DURATION_DEFAULT = 125;

        // private static final ThreadMXBean threadBean =
        // ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();

        public static final long getNanoTime() {
            // return threadBean.getCurrentThreadCpuTime();// not good, runs at
            // some time slice resolution
            return System.nanoTime();
        }

        public static class Result {
            public String name;
            public long   iterations;
            public long   totalTime; // nanoseconds

            public Result(String name, long iterations, long startTime, long endTime) {
                this.name = name;
                this.iterations = iterations;
                this.totalTime = endTime - startTime;
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                final double totalTimeMSecs = ((double) totalTime) / NANOS_PER_MSEC;

                final BigDecimal avgTimeMsecs = new BigDecimal(this.totalTime).divide(new BigDecimal(this.iterations).multiply(new BigDecimal(NANOS_PER_MSEC)),
                        BIGDECIMAL_PRECISION, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

                final String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append(name).append(newLine);
                sb.append("    ").append("iterations : ").append(iterations).append(newLine);
                sb.append("    ").append("total time : ").append(totalTimeMSecs).append(" ms").append(newLine);
                sb.append("    ").append("avg time   : ").append(avgTimeMsecs).append(" ms").append(newLine);
                return sb.toString();
            }
        }

        public static <T> Result executionTime(final String name, final long iterations, final long warmupIterations, final Callable<T> test) throws Exception {
            // vars
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            T ret;
            long startTime;
            long endTime;

            // warmup
            for (long i = 0; i < warmupIterations; ++i)
                ret = test.call();

            // actual benchmark iterations
            {
                startTime = getNanoTime();
                for (long i = 0; i < iterations; ++i)
                    ret = test.call();
                endTime = getNanoTime();
            }

            // return result
            return new Result(name, iterations, startTime, endTime);
        }

        /**
         * Auto tuned execution time measurement for test callbacks with steady
         * execution time
         * 
         * @param name
         * @param test
         * @return
         * @throws Exception
         */
        public static <T> Result executionTimeAutotuned(final String name, final Callable<T> test) throws Exception {
            final long autoTuningMinIterations = AUTOTUNING_MIN_ITERATIONS_DEFAULT;
            final long autoTuningMinDuration = AUTOTUNING_MIN_DURATION_DEFAULT;

            final long benchmarkTargetDuration = BENCHMARK_TARGET_DURATION_DEFAULT;
            final long benchmarkMinIterations = BENCHMARK_MIN_ITERATIONS_DEFAULT;
            final long benchmarkMaxIterations = BENCHMARK_MAX_ITERATIONS_DEFAULT;

            // vars
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            T ret;
            final int prevThreadPriority;
            long warmupIterations = 0;
            long autoTuningDuration = 0;
            long iterations = benchmarkMinIterations;
            long startTime;
            long endTime;

            // store current thread priority and set it to max
            prevThreadPriority = Thread.currentThread().getPriority();
            Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);

            // warmup and iteration count tuning
            {
                final long autoTuningMinTimeNanos = autoTuningMinDuration * NANOS_PER_MSEC;
                long autoTuningConsecutiveLoops = 1;
                double avgExecutionTime = 0;

                do {
                    {
                        startTime = getNanoTime();
                        for (long i = 0; i < autoTuningConsecutiveLoops; ++i, ++warmupIterations) {
                            ret = test.call();
                        }
                        endTime = getNanoTime();
                        autoTuningDuration += (endTime - startTime);
                    }
                    avgExecutionTime = ((double) autoTuningDuration) / ((double) (warmupIterations));
                    if ((autoTuningDuration >= autoTuningMinTimeNanos) && (warmupIterations >= autoTuningMinIterations)) {
                        break;
                    } else {
                        final double remainingAutotuningIterations = ((double) (autoTuningMinTimeNanos - autoTuningDuration)) / avgExecutionTime;
                        autoTuningConsecutiveLoops = Math.max(1, Math.min(Integer.MAX_VALUE, (long) Math.ceil(remainingAutotuningIterations)));
                    }
                } while (warmupIterations < Integer.MAX_VALUE);

                final double requiredIterations = ((double) benchmarkTargetDuration * NANOS_PER_MSEC) / avgExecutionTime;
                iterations = Math.max(1, Math.min(benchmarkMaxIterations, (long) Math.ceil(requiredIterations)));
            }

            // actual benchmark iterations
            {
                startTime = getNanoTime();
                for (long i = 0; i < iterations; ++i)
                    ret = test.call();
                endTime = getNanoTime();
            }

            // restore previous thread priority
            Thread.currentThread().setPriority(prevThreadPriority);

            // return result
            return new Result(name, iterations, startTime, endTime);
        }
    }

    public static void executeBenchmark(int inputSize, ArrayList<Benchmark.Result> results) {
        // final int[] inputArray = { 15, 8, 6, 3, 11, 1, 2, 0, 14, 13, 7, 9, 4,
        // 10, 5, 12 };
        final int[] inputArray = TestDataFactory.createIntArray(inputSize, TestDataFactory.ElementOrder.Random);

        try {
            // compare against Arrays.sort()
            {
                final int[] ref = inputArray.clone();
                Arrays.sort(ref);
                {
                    int[] temp = inputArray.clone();
                    BubbleSort.sort(temp);
                    if (!Arrays.equals(temp, ref))
                        throw new Exception("BubbleSort.sort() failed");
                }
                {
                    int[] temp = inputArray.clone();
                    OrbitSort.sort(temp);
                    if (!Arrays.equals(temp, ref))
                        throw new Exception("OrbitSort.sort() failed");
                }
            }

            results.add(Benchmark.executionTimeAutotuned("Arrays.sort()", new Callable<Void>() {
                @Override
                public Void call() throws Exception {
                    int[] temp = Arrays.copyOf(inputArray, inputArray.length);
                    Arrays.sort(temp);
                    return null;
                }
            }));
            results.add(Benchmark.executionTimeAutotuned("BubbleSort.sort()", new Callable<Void>() {
                @Override
                public Void call() throws Exception {
                    int[] temp = Arrays.copyOf(inputArray, inputArray.length);
                    BubbleSort.sort(temp);
                    return null;
                }
            }));
            results.add(Benchmark.executionTimeAutotuned("OrbitSort.sort()", new Callable<Void>() {
                @Override
                public Void call() throws Exception {
                    int[] temp = Arrays.copyOf(inputArray, inputArray.length);
                    OrbitSort.sort(temp);
                    return null;
                }
            }));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Benchmark.Result> results = new ArrayList<Benchmark.Result>();

        for (int i = 16; i <= 16384; i <<= 1) {
            results.clear();
            executeBenchmark(i, results);
            System.out.println("input size : " + i);
            System.out.println("");
            for (Benchmark.Result result : results) {
                System.out.print(result.toString());
            }
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Waw! Thank you. It's worst than BubbleSort, right? I'd like to know its performance on partially sorted arrays. I'll make some experiments soon.

Comment: Yes, although your algo possibly doesn't get optimized well due to the way it is implemented. I'll add the benchmark code after some cleanup.

Comment: java.util.Arrays.sort() is Quick Sort for larger n

Comment: Thanks for the hint, i corrected that. It is even mentioned in the docs.

Comment: So is it broken ? Or is your testing array too small ?

Comment: It was the same array as Josell posted, so most probably yes.

Comment: Wait, those numbers don't make sense.  How is Bubble sort 2x faster than quicksort?  Are you repeatedly sorting the same array?  If so, your numbers for bubble sort would be wrong, because after doing O(n^2) work for the initial sort, bubble sort would run in O(n) time afterwards because the array was sorted.

Comment: Yes then. If you do the test with an array of, let's say, 10 thousand, 100 thousand, and 1 million items, you will get a better indication of the behavior of each implementation.

Comment: @templatetypedef that result is perfectly fine for small arrays.

Comment: It seems Java 7 uses a hybrid sorting algorithm for optimization.

Comment: @mmgp- Oh, never mind, I thought that the array had size 10000000, not that the test did 10000000 iterations.  My mistake.

Comment: @templatetypedef I believed the same!

Comment: I've updated the results. This is near something, one would expect. Note, that array cloning charges in aswell.

Comment: @Sam Thanks! That's more accurate test.

Comment: You're welcome! Just added the source code. Just threw everything into one class, so you may review all that. Note, that i dropped my former, reflection based approach, where the overhead was just too large.

Comment: Thank you! That source code can be very useful for more tests.

Comment: My pleasure. I've updated the whole facility a bit, now, theres a first draft of an autotuned benchmark method and timing with nanoseconds instead of milliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

It is O(n^2) (assuming it works, I am not sure about that), as to already exists - maybe - it is not really original, as it can be considered a variation of a trivial sorting implementation, but I doubt if there is any published algorithm which is exactly the same as this one, specifically one with two consecutive inner loops.

I am not saying it is without merit, there can be a use case for which its behavior is uniquely efficient (maybe where reading is much faster than writing, and cache behavior benefits its access pattern).

To see why it is O(n^2), think about the first n/6 outer loop iterations, the inner loops run on O(n) length O(n) times.

Comment: Thank you! I think it can be modified to have only a inner loop.