# Why aren't results closer together? (I'm only doing one trial)

Tags: java, nanotime

I wrote a program to time certain square root algorithms

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
public class ScienceFairTwo {
    public static final BigDecimal TWO = new BigDecimal(2);
    public static final BigDecimal SQRT_TWO = new BigDecimal("1.4142135623730950488016887242096980785696718753769480731766797379907324784621070388503875343276415727");
    public static final BigDecimal TOLERANCE = BigDecimal.ONE.scaleByPowerOfTen(-100);
    public static long[] NewtonMethod() {
        int iterations = 0; // so far, we haven't done any iterations
        BigDecimal a = BigDecimal.ONE; // set a to be one
        long start = System.nanoTime(); // start the timer
        while(a.subtract(SQRT_TWO).abs().compareTo(TOLERANCE) >= 0) { // while our decimal isn't close enough to the square root of two
            a = a.add(TWO.divide(a, 100, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)).divide(TWO); // set a to (a + 2/a)/2
            iterations++; // add one to our iteration counter
        }
        return new long[] {System.nanoTime() - start, iterations}; // return the time taken and the iterations taken
    }
    public static long[] BhaskaraBrounckerAlgorithm() {
        int iterations = 0; // so far, we haven't done any iterations
        BigDecimal a = BigDecimal.ONE; // set a to be one
        long start = System.nanoTime(); // start the timer
        while(a.subtract(SQRT_TWO).abs().compareTo(TOLERANCE) >= 0) { // while our decimal isn't close enough to the square root of two
            a = a.add(TWO).divide(a.add(BigDecimal.ONE), 100, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP); // set a to (a+2)/(a+1)
            iterations++; // add one to our iteration counter
        }
        return new long[] {System.nanoTime() - start, iterations};  // return the time taken and the iterations taken
    }
    public static long[] MidpointMethod()
    {
        int iterations = 0; // so far, we haven't done any iterations
        BigDecimal a = BigDecimal.ONE; // set a to be one
        BigDecimal b = TWO; // set b to be two  
        long start = System.nanoTime(); // start the timer
        while(a.add(b).divide(TWO).subtract(SQRT_TWO).abs().compareTo(TOLERANCE) >= 0) { // while our decimals aren't close enough to the square root of two
            if(a.multiply(a).subtract(TWO).abs().compareTo(b.multiply(b).subtract(TWO).abs()) == 1)  // if a is farther from the square root of two than b
                a = a.add(b).divide(TWO); // set a to be the average of a and b
            else // if a is closer to the square root of two than b
                b = a.add(b).divide(TWO); // set b to be the average of a and b
            iterations++; // add one to our iteration counter
        }
        return new long[] {System.nanoTime() - start, iterations}; // return the time taken and the iterations taken
    }
    public static long[] SecantMethod()
    {
        BigDecimal a = BigDecimal.ONE; // set a to be one
        BigDecimal b = TWO; // set b to be two
        BigDecimal b_old = TWO; // set b_old to be two (this is a transferring variable)
        long start = System.nanoTime(); // start the timer
        int iterations = 0; // so far, we haven't done any iterations
        while(a.add(b).divide(TWO).subtract(SQRT_TWO).abs().compareTo(TOLERANCE) >= 0) { // // while our decimals aren't close enough to the square root of two
            b_old = b; // set b_old to be b
            b = a.multiply(b).add(TWO).divide(a.add(b), 100, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP); // set b to be (ab + 2)/(a+b)
            a = b_old; // set a to be the previous value of b
            iterations++; // add one to our iterations counter
        }
        return new long[] {System.nanoTime() - start, iterations}; // return the time taken and the iterations taken
    } 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.printf("Newton Iteration: %f milliseconds (%d iterations taken)\n", NewtonMethod()[0] / 10e6, NewtonMethod()[1]); // print the results
        System.out.printf("Midpoint Method: %f milliseconds (%d iterations taken)\n", MidpointMethod()[0] / 10e6, MidpointMethod()[1]); // print the results
        System.out.printf("Secant Method: %f milliseconds (%d iterations taken)\n", SecantMethod()[0] / 10e6, SecantMethod()[1]); // print the results
        System.out.printf("Bhaskara-Brouncker Algorithm: %f milliseconds (%d iterations taken)\n", BhaskaraBrounckerAlgorithm()[0] / 10e6, BhaskaraBrounckerAlgorithm()[1]); // print the results
    }
}
```

I don't want to do 100/1000 trials because I need to put this program on a science fair board, so I don't want to complicate the program by using benchmarking, etc. However, when I do this,  the results I get vary a lot. For example, once i got

Newton Iteration: 0.466200 milliseconds (8 iterations taken)
Midpoint Method: 21.090700 milliseconds (330 iterations taken)
Secant Method: 0.134500 milliseconds (11 iterations taken)
Bhaskara-Brouncker Algorithm: 1.315300 milliseconds (132 iterations taken)

another time i got
Newton Iteration: 0.550700 milliseconds (8 iterations taken)
Midpoint Method: 23.168400 milliseconds (330 iterations taken)
Secant Method: 0.130400 milliseconds (11 iterations taken)
Bhaskara-Brouncker Algorithm: 1.078100 milliseconds (132 iterations taken)

now I'm getting
Newton Iteration: 0.469500 milliseconds (8 iterations taken)
Midpoint Method: 22.437700 milliseconds (330 iterations taken)
Secant Method: 0.189200 milliseconds (11 iterations taken)
Bhaskara-Brouncker Algorithm: 1.807600 milliseconds (132 iterations taken)

### They simply aren't very close together. Why is this so? I am doing the same thing each time, and java can't possibly be optimizing because I am only doing it once each time I run.

So what is the best way to proceed? There are a few possible solutions:

- Just do one trial

  - advantages: Java can't optimize
  - disadvantages: Not very consistent (as seen above)
- Do 1000 trials

  - advantages: pretty consistent
  - disadvantages: java will optimize so inaccurate results
- Do 1000 trials, but change the value we are approximating the square root for each time using rand

  - advantages: pretty accurate, no optimization
  - disadvantages: answer will vary each time due to random
- Do 969 trials, but each time do the square root of 2, 3, ..., 1000 (excluding 1,4,..,961)

  - advantages: pretty accurate, no optimization
  - disadvantages:

I am leaning towards the last one. Is this a good idea?

Comment: *"...so I don't want to complicate the program by using benchmarking..."* It's a ***science fair***. Do good science, and make what you put on the board the headline result. Not doing proper science in the name of brevity is surely the anti-goal.

Comment: But it is a middle school science fair, and I don't even understand benchmarking (yes, I tried reading about it)

Comment: They are close together and Java does a whole lot of things in the background (e.g. garbage collection) which may or may not happen at the time you measure. Also your pc might have an important task that needs to be executed while you measure. Then you have dynamically scaling CPUs that may change how fast they run to conserve energy. If you want it close add some loop that repeats the test a few thousand times.

Comment: You could start with this benchmark class: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14174988/1175253

Comment: The problem is i don't even understand the code, and I need to put the code on the board with explanations.

Comment: As for looping it 1000 times, java would optimize if I did that.

Comment: Admittedly, that code is not well documented. But for this kind of investigation, you need to do that. Optimization & loops are not a problem. Who cares about a few microseconds, if the fuction is just called once? You already got the answers. As for a possible cause of difference: You're using BigDecimal. The time consumption of operations does also depend on the values of the operands.

Comment: I added more to the question

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about differences of 0.1 milliseconds. Often the same algorithm will fluctuate in run time by this much because of load. At 0.1 milliseconds the difference is minuscule, if you want to ensure that you avoid 'optimization' then you should write your program in a less managed language, possibly c or even assembly but all algorithms I've seen fluctuate by these small amounts from run to run.

Comment: But the problem is that difference is about how long they actually take to run. I need precise precise results, which is why I document 3 options - just do one trial, average over 1000, or keep changing the square root.

Comment: Also, I don't know c or assembly, and I need to be able to explain the program.

Comment: Do you think the results I am getting now are sufficiently accurate? (is it OK for them to vary this much)?

Comment: I think that there is uncertainty in all science, that is why statistics was invented and why we run tests multiple times. I would suggest running the program many times and averaging the resulting outcomes but I would also greatly recommend using c. Java was based on c syntactically so if you have the time and really do want to make a precise comparison I would definitely recommend c.